# POSTGRESQL strange update time?

Tags: postgresql

Hy all,
i'm trying to find an explanation for a strange behavior happening on postgres from a vbnet application.

First:

1) vbnet windows form application

2) postgres 9.6 on win7 with raid5 (default installation so VACUUM on for all tables)

3) npgsql 3.1.9

4) a table with 250 rows and a unique index on the field used in the where clause of the update statement

5) Un update inside a transaction

the strange behavior is that this update:

```
UPDATE work.wip_pallets SET 
  WPAL_DATA_INI = value ,
  STAZ_ID = value, 
  WPAL_PRESENZA_CEPA = value, 
  WPAL_SCARTO = value 
WHERE CEPA_CODICE =filter value;
```

normally runs in 0 or less than 50ms but in some occasion it takes 400ms or more! Randomly (?) 
The update have to run to store the start time of an operation and is supposed to fire at a frequence that could 
be less then 1s but it is not predictable (it could take longer).

Anyone experienced the same? 
It is normally? 
Do you have some actions that i can try to make in order to identify a problem?

If possible i can provide some others information if required.

Thanks

P.S.
... sorry for my english ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possibilities:

1. Overloaded I/O system.
2. Concurrent transactions locking the table or the row.

You could turn on [auto_explain](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auto-explain.html):

- Add `auto_explain` to `shared_preload_libraries` in `postgresql.conf`.
- Set `auto_explain.log_analyze = on` and `auto_explain.log_buffers = on`.
- Set `auto_explain.log_min_duration = 100` to log everything that takes more than 100 ms.
- Restart PostgreSQL.

Then you'll get execution plans from the long runs in the log. These should provide some information what is going on.

Comment: Tanks for your reply but 1) actually the application is in test and the system load is very low 2) there is only one process that fire the update

Comment: Try auto_explain as described in the extended answer.

Comment: Well, first thanks for your suggestion. I've activated the log for any stament that require more than 200ms and i've verified that when a client fire something that require more than 200ms it is stored in the log. At the moment, when the strange update happens, in the postgresql log there isn't any trace of it! I suspect there is something related to npgsql or network. The forst two things i've done are: 1) update npgsql to 3.2.6 2) disable any defender or firewall services on the clients pc (win10). We will see. For the moment i think you helped me a lot! thanks.