# PostgreSQL strange UPDATE time 2?

Tags: postgresql

As I reported in my [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48772666/6464308), I'm faced with a problem running my VB.NET application with POSTGRESQL 9.6 and Npgsql 3.2.6 on WIN10. The problem is a strange long time required to perform some DML statements on a table with 250 rows (normally few ms but sometime 0.8s!).

As Laurenz Albe suggested in response to my previous post, I activated the log on PostgreSQL but no statements are logged when the strange behavior occurs.
The PostgreSQL DB server is connected to the main pc by a GB lan.

In my application I have a separate thread in which I perform my tasks (including activities on DB).

In this thread i call the update this way:

```vb
Dim vT As DateTime = Now
'apertura lavorazione
vRet = mMaster.DB.apriLavorazione(vPallet)
Dim vS As String = (Now - vT).Seconds.ToString + ":" + (Now - vT).Milliseconds.ToString
```

The update function is something like this:

```vb
Function apriLavorazione(ByRef pPallet As clsPallet) As clsCallRes

        Dim vObjRet As clsCallRes = New clsCallRes

        Dim vConn As NpgsqlConnection = Nothing
        Dim vCommand As NpgsqlCommand = Nothing
        Dim vPar As NpgsqlParameter

        Try

            'creo la connessione
            vConn = New NpgsqlConnection(mConnectionString)
            vConn.Open()

            pPallet.intermedio1 = Now

            'creo il comando dalla connessione ed associo la transazione
            vCommand = vConn.CreateCommand()

            pPallet.WPAL_DATA_INI = DateTime.Now()

            vCommand.CommandText = "UPDATE work.wip_pallets SET WPAL_DATA_INI = @dataini" +
                                   " ,STAZ_ID = @stazid, WPAL_PRESENZA_CEPA = @presenzacepa, WPAL_SCARTO = @scarto" +
                                   " WHERE CEPA_CODICE = @cepacodice;"

            vPar = New NpgsqlParameter
            vPar.ParameterName = "dataini"
            vPar.NpgsqlDbType = NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Timestamp
            vPar.Value = pPallet.WPAL_DATA_INI.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff")
            vCommand.Parameters.Add(vPar)

            vPar = New NpgsqlParameter
            vPar.ParameterName = "stazid"
            vPar.NpgsqlDbType = NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Integer
            vPar.Value = pPallet.STAZ_ID
            vCommand.Parameters.Add(vPar)

            vPar = New NpgsqlParameter
            vPar.ParameterName = "presenzacepa"
            vPar.NpgsqlDbType = NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Integer
            vPar.Value = pPallet.WPAL_PRESENZA_CEPA
            vCommand.Parameters.Add(vPar)

            vPar = New NpgsqlParameter
            vPar.ParameterName = "scarto"
            vPar.NpgsqlDbType = NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Integer
            vPar.Value = pPallet.WPAL_SCARTO
            vCommand.Parameters.Add(vPar)

            vPar = New NpgsqlParameter
            vPar.ParameterName = "cepacodice"
            vPar.NpgsqlDbType = NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Varchar
            vPar.Value = pPallet.CEPA_CODICE
            vCommand.Parameters.Add(vPar)

            vCommand.Prepare()

            vCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()


        Catch ex As Exception
            vObjRet.err = True
            vObjRet.message = String.Concat("apriLavorazione:", ex.Message)
        Finally
            vConn.Close()
        End Try

        Return vObjRet

    End Function
```

I don't think is a code that can require about one second!

Do you have any idea what the problem might be?

1) npgsql on thread?

2) network latency?

3) bad code for multithreaded application?

4) ????

Comment: My bet is on the database connection. Verify if you are using connection pooling.

Comment: Thanks. My connectionstring is on the form of: UserID=myUser;Password=myPassword;Host=myRemoteHost;Port=5432;Database=myDataBase; so pooling takes the default values (enabled, max pooled connection 100, min pooled connection 1). How could be this a problem?

Comment: If two requests arrive simultaneously (not unheard of on the internet), the second one my have to create a new connection (min pooled = 1).

Comment: Yes, time to establish the connection is one possibility. Try to set `log_min_duration_statement = 500` in `postgresql.conf` (and reload) to log all statements that take longer than half a second. If your query does not show up, the time is not spent executing the query.

Comment: As you can see from the code of the procedure, i place a time measurement after the connection.open(). The difference between the start time (vT) and that value (.intermedio1) is always 0. I did what you've suggested and no statements are logged.

Comment: Have you been able to reproduce the problem with a higher "min pooled" ?

Answer (score 0):

I've moved the DB on the same machine as the application that use it. At this time (and i hope for the future) the strange update time never occurred again. I suspect something related to network latency.

Thanks for your time reading this post.